# std::string::find does not work as expected, when the substring is at the beginning

Tags: c++, string, stl

For some reason std::string:npos is returned when the substring I'm searching for is at the beginning of string.

```
const char delim[] = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L'};

std::string::size_type pos = 0;
std::string bigString = "HELLO";

while(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    pos = bigString.find(delim, pos);
    ...
}
```

the specified pos should be inclusive, but incase of 0 it is not and the function returns npos. It does however work if i specify the size of the string im searching for.

```
pos = bigString.find(delim, pos, 4);
```

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: You forgot to 0-terminate your `delim`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trivial.

Comment: @H2CO3 that would apply to most SO questions :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Indeed... :/

Comment: terminate the string!

Comment: Oh, of course, I should have realized it expects a null terminated string, I was working with hexadecimal values and bytestreams, which made me forgot everything, apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::string::find` overload you are using expects a null terminated character string, so

```
const char delim[] = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', '\0'};
```

Comment: Or just `const char delim[] = "HELL";`

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect form of member function find of class std::basic_string. As your searched string delim has no the terminating zero character you have to specify explicitly how many characters of it you are going to find. Otherwise the size of the string will be calculated incorrectly and the behaviour of the program is undefined. So use the following form of the find

```
size_type find(const charT* s, size_type pos, size_type n) const;
```

Your code will look the following way

```
const char delim[] = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L'};

std::string::size_type pos = 0;
std::string bigString = "HELLO";

while(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    pos = bigString.find( delim, pos, sizeof( delim ) );
    ...
}
```